# Grails, SpringSecurity - disable redirect if not logged

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

How can I configure grails to not redirect person/user to login page if he try to access secure resource. I just want to send 401 status error insed of redirect to homepage.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is configure the authenticationEntryPoint, which can usually be done in spring/resources.groovy.  Having difficulty finding a notation for it in the Spring Security Core plugin documentation, but here's a Jira ticket discussion that references it:

https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/issues/51

In one of our projects, we wanted to send back a 403 response, so we added this line to resources.groovy:

authenticationEntryPoint(org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint)

Hope that helps.

Comment: authenticationEntryPoint(org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint)
worked perfectly in Grails3 3.3.0