# Grails+SpringSecurityCore: how to respond custom HTTP staus when not authorized?

Tags: grails, spring-security

How to respond any http status error (403 for example) when user not logged in?

AS IS: there is an implemented user authentication using spring security core. User is able to log in with username and password. When user tries to access any resource before authentocation, system redirects to log in page and respond 200 OK HTTP status.

Implemented on Grails 2.4.3 + SpringSecurityCore 2.0-RC4

TO BE: 200 OK status should be changed to any error (like 403)

Comment: Why you need that? What wrong with just redirecting to the login page with 200 status? 
BTW: if request via AJAX it will just return 403(401?) status code.

Comment: @Koloritnij thank you for responce! There is an application with integrated browser. User is already authenricated in this application with same credentials. We need avoid user enter credentials when access any page. Integrated browser can handle response and if it has 403 error, application will send in background an authorization request like //server/login?login=user&pass=pwd. And after this application will send original request again.  ( I know, rest authentication will be the best idea here, but depending on complexity of other changes this idea looks better)

Comment: Not sure, but try to add this one to the resources.groovy
authenticationEntryPoint(classFor('authenticationEntryPoint', Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint))

Comment: @Koloritnij thanks a lot! Your suggestion works. After some improuvements i've got the desired behaviour. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found (much thanks to @Koloritnij): add to resources.groovy

```
authenticationEntryPoint(org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint)
```

This question happens related to 
[Grails, SpringSecurity - disable redirect if not logged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337293/grails-springsecurity-disable-redirect-if-not-logged)